# Save offline map with MapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

In iOS app is there a chance to save map tile for offline use (not third part map or bitmap but the one used from Apple)?

Comment: What you ask is not clear. Would you like to save the image of the map, map tiles, a position in order to redisplay that map position?
These are all different.

Comment: Pretty impossible. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696929/ios-mapkit-cache-maps